# Problem when deleting records from mongodb using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

So I have some 50 document ID's. My python **veno** list contains document ID's as shown below.

```
5ddfc565bd293f3dbf502789
5ddfc558bd293f3dbf50263b
5ddfc558bd293f3dbf50264f
5ddfc558bd293f3dbf50264d
5ddfc565bd293f3dbf502792
```

But when I am trying to delete those 50 document ID's then I am finding a hard time. Let me explain - I need to run my python script over and over again in order to delete all the 50 documents. The first time I run my script it will delete some 10, the next time I run then it deletes 18 and so on. My for loop is pretty simple as shown below

```
for i in veno:
            vv =  i[0]
            db.Products2.delete_many({'_id': ObjectId(vv)})
```

Answer (score 0):

If your list is just the ids, then you want:

```
for i in veno:
    db.Products2.delete_many({'_id': ObjectId(i)})
```

full example:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson import ObjectId

db = MongoClient()['testdatabase']

# Test data setup
veno = [str(db.testcollection.insert_one({'a': 1}).inserted_id) for _ in range(50)]

# Quick peek to see we have the data correct
for x in range(3): print(veno[x])

print(f'Document count before delete: {db.testcollection.count_documents({})}')

for i in veno:
    db.testcollection.delete_many({'_id': ObjectId(i)})

print(f'Document count after delete:  {db.testcollection.count_documents({})}')
```

gives:

```
5ddffc5ac9a13622dbf3d88e
5ddffc5ac9a13622dbf3d88f
5ddffc5ac9a13622dbf3d890
Document count before delete: 50
Document count after delete:  0
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont have any mongo instance to test but what about

```
veno = [
'5ddfc565bd293f3dbf502789',
'5ddfc558bd293f3dbf50263b',
'5ddfc558bd293f3dbf50264f',
'5ddfc558bd293f3dbf50264d',
'5ddfc565bd293f3dbf502792',
]

# Or for your case (Whatever you have in **veno**)
veno = [vv[0] for vv in veno]
####

db.Products2.delete_many({'_id': {'$in':[ObjectId(vv) for vv in veno]}})
```

If this doesnt work, then maybe this

```
db.Products2.remove({'_id': {'$in':[ObjectId(vv) for vv in veno]}})
```

From what I understand, **delete_many**'s first argument is filter, so 
its designed in such a way, that you dont delete particular documents
but instead documents that satisfies particular condition.
In above case, best is delete all documents at once by saying -> delete all documents whose **_id** is in **($in)** the list **[ObjectId(vv) for vv in veno]**